# How to shard input to Sagemaker ProcessingJob based on S3 folder?

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I'm trying to use Sagemaker ProcessingJob to process a huge s3 bucket on multiple instances.

The s3 bucket is structured to have multiple input files of each job in the same folder, e.g.

```
job1/
  a.jpg
  b.json
  c.proto
job2/
  a.jpg
  b.json
  c.proto
...
```

Where a.jpg,b.json,c.proto are required together for processing.

How can i force Sagemaker to shard jobs according to the folder structure, instead of individual files?

I tried looking for appropriate sharding strategy, but found only ShardByS3Key or FullyReplicated.

Comment: do you need a single job to process all the bucket, or to spread the bucket content over multiple independent processing jobs?

Comment: I need to spread the bucket content over multiple independent processing jobs, to significantly reduce processing time.